# AS3 Flash media text color

Tags: text, colors, chat

I am using FMS to build a chat application. To set the text colors in a chat room can this be done in client-side, or, would it require some server-side coding? Which my knowledge is limited. I want the text colors to be in blue and red but im unsure how to approach this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can do it both ways, server or client.

for example:

```
var myColor:String = "#FF0000";
nc.call("msgFromUser", myName, myColor, msg);
```